# Error while running spark on standalone cluster

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to run a simple Spark code on standalone cluster. Below is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("even-numbers").setMaster("spark://sumit-Inspiron-N5110:7077")
    sc = SparkContext(conf)
    inp = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
    even = inp.filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0)).collect()
    for i in even:
        print(i)
```

but, I'm getting error stating " Could not parse Master URL":

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: '<pyspark.conf.SparkConf object at 0x7fb27e864850>'
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2760)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/01/07 16:59:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/01/07 16:59:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-0d71782f-617f-44b1-9593-b9cd9267757e
```

I also tried setting the master as 'local', but it didn't work. Can someone help?

And yes, the command to run the job is

**./bin/spark-submit even.py**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace your following line

```
sc = SparkContext(conf)
```

with

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

you should have it solved.

Comment: I guess with Spark 2.2, (conf=conf) have become mandatory syntax. I remember, sc = SparkContext(conf) have worked with earlier version. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: lifesaver.!! My biggest complaint with spark is the syntax, too much variability version to version!!